# How to add tooltip on magento 2 product page?

Tags: magento2

How to add tooltip to custom option labels in the product page? For example, a tooltip next to text SIZE?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know below is the best solution but it is working fine.

Copy:

> magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

To:

> magentoRoot/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

1. Add `tooltip` class to `label` tag in foreach.
2. Add below code before closing `</label>`

   ```
   <?php if($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()=='Color'){ ?>
       <span class="tooltiptext">This popup for color</span>
   <?php }elseif($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()=='Size'){ ?>
       <span class="tooltiptext">This popup for size</span>
   <?php }else{ ?>
       <span class="tooltiptext">This can be anything</span>
   <?php } ?>
   ```
3. Add below CSS at the end of file Or in CSS file

   ```
   .tooltip {
       position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
       border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
   }

   .tooltip .tooltiptext {
       visibility: hidden;
       width: 120px;
       background-color: #555;
       color: #fff;
       text-align: center;
       border-radius: 6px;
       padding: 5px 0;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 1;
       bottom: 125%;
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: -60px;
       opacity: 0;
       transition: opacity 0.3s;
   }

   .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
       content: "";
       position: absolute;
       top: 100%;
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: -5px;
       border-width: 5px;
       border-style: solid;
       border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
   }
   .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
       visibility: visible;
       opacity: 1;
   }
   ```

Overall Your file will be:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable*/
$_product    = $block->getProduct();
$_attributes = $block->decorateArray($block->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <div class="field configurable required">
            <label class="tooltip label" for="attribute<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()) ?></span>
        <?php if($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()=='Color'){ ?>
            <span class="tooltiptext">this popup for color</span>
        <?php }elseif($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()=='Size'){ ?>
            <span class="tooltiptext">this popup for size</span>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <span class="tooltiptext">this can be anything</span>
        <?php } ?>
            </label>


            <div class="control">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-selector="super_attribute[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                        id="attribute<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>"
                        class="super-attribute-select">
                    <option value=""><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "configurable": {
                    "spConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>,
                    "gallerySwitchStrategy": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar('gallery_switch_strategy',
                        'Magento_ConfigurableProduct') ?: 'replace'; ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
<style>
    .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    }

    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s;
    }

    .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        }
</style>
```

**Note:** You need to change label code in condition with your attribute label code

CSS source: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)

Answer (score -1):

You can always use the build-in tooltips in Magento 2 (I'm using v2.3.2) with attribute: "title" which can work on label, div and other elements, example for adding tooltip for facebook menu item in the topup-menu:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item">
   <a href="www.facebook.com" title="facebook" target="_blank">
      <img src="facebook_icon.png"/>
   </a>
</li>
```

screen shot:

[image: facebook menu tooltip]